# For loop through a parents child pages - wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, for-loop, while-loop, parent-child

Is it possible to for loop through a specific parents children in Wordpress?

At the moment I have looked into:

```
$post->post_parent == '2'
```

but thats more of an if statement condition. 
Also I tried the following, but I need a specific parents children.

```
while(have_posts()) : the_post();
```

the following article helped me: 
https://wordpress.org/support/topic/displaying-wp_list_pages-and-custom-fields

Answer (score 0):

You can use a custom query:

```
$the_query = new WP_Query(array(
    'post_parent' => 2
));

while ($the_query->have_posts())
{
    $the_query->the_post();
    echo get_the_title();
}

wp_reset_postdata();
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for me, just shows an empty page. Plus there are no errors in the console.

Comment: It may not work depending on where you put the code; plus, the `2` is an example, you have to replace it with the right post ID - see @Pieter Goosen answer.

Comment: Yes, i have replaced the 2 with the correct ID :) Maybe where I have positioned this it doesn't like it. On my page.php page I check if the page is the specified parent, and then I include another php file where I do the above code. However - I have an echo statement at the beginning and it is not executed when the above code is in the file but is execute when it is taken out. The file does not include any other code.